# I think we should remove the [windows-10-final] tag synonym

Tags: support, tags, tag-cleanup-request

Previously, [windows-10-final] referred to non-preview Windows 10 builds (i.e. "final" meaning Windows 10 after its official release, when the preview period was over), and served as a tag synonym for [windows-10].

However, this is confusing in light of the fact that 22H2 is now to be the final version of Windows 10 (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information)

It's now possible to interpret "final" as meaning any of:

- Any non-preview build
- Any build after the last preview build of version 1507
- Version 22H2

Based on this, I would suggest the [windows-10-final] tag synonym is now just confusing, and that it should just be deleted.